# App crashes giving index out of bounds in logcat while adding footer to listview

Tags: android, listview, footer, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a listview which loads more listitems when it reaches 20rh listitem using onscroll listener

I want to add a footer saying loading more while more listitems are getting loaded

When i reach the 20th  listitem the app crashes saying idex out of bounds in logct

**my activity**

```
public class InterActivity extends Activity 
{

SwipeMenuListView listview;
//ListView listview;

View mFooterView;






@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inter_layout);
    shrdPreference = new SharedPreference();


    //Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask

    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}




private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(InterActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Set progressdialog title
        //mProgressDialog.setTitle("BEGINNER CODES");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait loading ....");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.anim.progress_handler));
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();

    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // my do in backgroung process

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
    //  listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inter_layoutListView);

        listview = (SwipeMenuListView) findViewById(R.id.inter_layoutListView);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new FinalAdapter(InterActivity.this,
                                      codelist);
         mFooterView = LayoutInflater.from(InterActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null);                        

        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

//          setup onscrll listener

```
        listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                                                 int scrollState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int threshold = 1;
                    int count = listview.getCount();

                    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        if (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                            - threshold) {
                            // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask
                            new Loadmore().execute();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });




    }
}





private class Loadmore extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    listview.addFooterView(mFooterView);

        }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // my load mmore data process


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        int position = listview.getLastVisiblePosition();



    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listview.removeFooterView(mFooterView);


listview.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);


    }
}

   }
```

**logcat**

> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E
>   AndroidRuntime
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 9, size is 0 02-29
>   15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at  com.enlightenme.pac.FinalAdapter.getItem(FinalAdapter.java:55)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at com.enlightenme.pac.FinalAdapter.getView(FinalAdapter.java:83)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuAdapter.getView(SwipeMenuAdapter.java:65)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2588)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:681)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1339)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1639)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2427)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14938)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14938)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14938)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1694)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1552)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465) 02-29
>   15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14938)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14938) 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342
>   23342 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601) 02-29 15:53:11.546
>   23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2212)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2026)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1236)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5160)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
>   02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561) 02-29
>   15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
>
> 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 02-29
>   15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 02-29
>   15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 02-29 15:53:11.546 23342
>   23342 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365) 02-29
>   15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-29
>   15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-29 15:53:11.546
>   23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>   02-29 15:53:11.546 23342 23342 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at

**new logcat**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter
02-29 17:54:03.976 27184 27184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.widget.ListView.removeFooterView(ListView.java:396)
02-29 17:54:03.976 27184 27184 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.enlightenme.pac.InterActivity$Loadmore.onPostExecute(InterActivity.java:383)
```

Comment: Did you override the method in Adapter getCount()? if list null then return 0;  ?

Comment: @RameshKumar i did ovverride getcount and like this   
  return codeList.size();

Comment: add this line before return "if(codeList ==null || codeList.size<=0) return 0;" May it help

Comment: @RameshKumar i will try and let you know, thnx

Comment: @RameshKumar now the app crashes giving class cast exception posted the logcat in question PS,TNX

Comment: @RameshKumar did you have a look

Comment: It is giving ListView cast error. You do not need to remove the Footer comment the footer remove code and if there is error or not/

Comment: @RameshKumar tried doing so but now the footer is no visiblecand the list jumps to 1st list item after more items are loaded

Answer (score 1):

Create footer_view.xml and than just try it onCreate

```
View footerView =  ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
list.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: Broo i tried that aalso it gives nullpointerexception for the line listview.adddfooter(footerview); line

Comment: Have you define xml ? and after findview for listview write list.addFooterView

Comment: that is why instead of in ocreate i inflated the footer view in opostexecte of remotedatatask

Comment: You can findview for both in oncreate

Comment: you can try adding the view in `onWindowFocusChanged()` method. And it adding the view to the listview does not work, may be, try adding adding it to the layout that contains the listview, just make sure you add the rule to attach it below the listview.